# Least-square function with Accelerate framework?

Tags: ios, math, accelerate-framework

I have the problem:

[image]

I know that LAPACK has support for least square solving, can I do this with the Accelerate framework? Or do you have another suggestion for something that is optimized for ARM/Neon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the LAPACK function `dgels_` (which is part of Accelerate).  The documentation here http://www.math.utah.edu/software/lapack/lapack-d/dgels.html explains the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It's an [easy enough set of formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html) if your have n pairs (x, y) and the relationship is linear:

```
y = a*x + b
```

A more general solution for other functions can be had easily using linear algebra.